# Run PHP from JavaScript form submit

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Can anyone explain how to run PHP code from within javaScript for submit?

Currently I submit the form to a page.php, connect to MySQL, run some queries then build up the HTML and echo it out.

However, I want to do this without going to the page.php as I am trying to show the results in an ajax dialog using JQuery-UI. It works, just I have to submit to page.php to make it happen.

Would I do something like build up the code in Javascript writelin statements and dynamically load a div or something?

Comment: I don't exactly understand Your problem. You can submit data from form using Jquery ajax and on response load it to div. You need to use load(). Give more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `post()` method to send the request to page.php from JavaScript asynchronously. You can use the success option to show the dialog http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I see. Makes sense. Would you be familiar with a way to pass parameters to jQuery.Post so I dont have to have many functions? I have multiples forms that can submit different values. also, Would you now a way to dynamically pass the form to be submitted to the post(). The docs are fairly excellent. I had no idea jQuery was so powerful. Definitely worth become very familiar with.

Comment: @Axl Actually, I just looked and I learned something new. Just use $('#formId').serialize() to get all form data into a string for posting. So the line to submit a form would be jQuery.post("page.php", $("#formId").serialize()); To make it dynamic, just change the selector "#formId" to the form you want to submit

Comment: I get it. Thanks for the replies and thanks for showing my jQuery was pretty damn awesome.